# MySQL: update datetime values with incorrect format

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I am trying to fix values with incorrect datetime format.
The problem is that the following SELECT query is working, but the UPDATE query will fail.

Select works

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(created_at, '%d.%m.%Y %H:%i'), 
       STR_TO_DATE(updated_at, '%d.%m.%Y %H:%i')
FROM users 
WHERE DATE(created_at) IS NULL 
  AND DATE(updated_at) IS NULL;
```

Update fails

```
UPDATE users
   SET created_at = STR_TO_DATE(created_at, '%d.%m.%Y %H:%i'),
        updated_at = STR_TO_DATE(updated_at, '%d.%m.%Y %H:%i')
WHERE DATE(created_at) IS NULL
  AND DATE(updated_at) IS NULL;
```

With the following error

```
ERROR 1292 (22007): Incorrect datetime value: '12.05.2013 4:10'
```

Table description

```
+------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type            | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | bigint unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| username   | varchar(30)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at | varchar(20)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at | varchar(20)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Mysql version 8.0.26

P.S.

I am able to fix it using regex inside the where clause, but It doesn't look good

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide table description, some data examples?

Comment: Is it possible that you have a trigger on the table?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot save datetime in every format. you should keep on the supported format and in select you can change the format as much as you need.

> The DATETIME type is used for values that contain both date and time
> parts. MySQL retrieves and displays DATETIME values in ' YYYY-MM-DD
> hh:mm:ss ' format. The supported range is '1000-01-01 00:00:00' to
> '9999-12-31 23:59:59' . The TIMESTAMP data type is used for values
> that contain both date and time parts.

Try this update:

```
UPDATE users
   SET created_at = STR_TO_DATE(created_at, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'),
        updated_at = STR_TO_DATE(updated_at, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
WHERE DATE(created_at) IS NULL
  AND DATE(updated_at) IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query should not give any error for `12.05.2013 4:10` if the datatypes for created_at and updated_at are varchar (as mentioned in question). Please check below example:

Schema and insert statements:

```
 create table users ( id bigint unsigned , username   varchar(30), created_at  varchar(20) , updated_at  varchar(20));
 
 insert into users values(1,'A',STR_TO_DATE('12.05.2013 4:10', '%d.%m.%Y %H:%i'),STR_TO_DATE('12.05.2013 4:10', '%d.%m.%Y %H:%i'))
```

Select query:

```
 select * from users
```

Output:

| id | username | created_at | updated_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 2013-05-12 04:10:00 | 2013-05-12 04:10:00 |

Update query:

```
 UPDATE users
    SET created_at = STR_TO_DATE('12.05.2013 4:10', '%d.%m.%Y %H:%i'),
         updated_at = STR_TO_DATE(updated_at, '%d.%m.%Y %H:%i')
 WHERE DATE(created_at) IS NULL
   AND DATE(updated_at) IS NULL;
```

Select query:

```
 select * from users
```

Output:

| id | username | created_at | updated_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 2013-05-12 04:10:00 | 2013-05-12 04:10:00 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=aa71fc7e0e65e6ccb5d15ac1c06b5984)*

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. Which mysql version do you use?

Comment: I have checked these on 5.5,5.6,5.7 and 8.0.

Comment: Thanks for useful answer. It still not working for me in 8.0. I will try to figure out why. Maybe some global env or something.

Comment: Please check whether there is any trigger on users table.